# SAP JavaScript for % Increase Function

Tags: javascript

We have a Requirement, where Business always discuss to Increase or Decrease the Target sales value by some Integers, accordingly we have Input Enabled SAP WAD report which gives sale numbers. Moreover Now we have developed all of the Necessary Configuration to perform this %Increase Function but need this precise JavaScript code optimization on my existing code.

Logic is, I Select the Required multiple row Cells and subsequently admit to press the %Increase Button, a Prompt will pop-up and enter the required integer Values and say OK.

So,for that Input provided integer value, back-end code should perform the %Increase calculation and insert back to respective cell.

```
x = (Input Value/100)X Cell Value;
Result = Cell value X x
```

Here I need your help fix the JavaScript syntax correction.

The below Code performs 80% of my required function, but only need 20% of modification on that.

```
function sapbi_rig_plan_Per_Increase(content){

  if ('undefined' == typeof(content) ) content = '';

  if (content == null) content = '';

  var info = sapbi_rig_plan_inf;

  if (sapbi_rig_plan_isValidState(info) === false){
    alert('Please select the range.');
    return;
  }

  var  content = prompt("Please enter value", " ");

  if (isNumber(content ) == true){
    var cell;   
    for(var cntSel = 0; cntSel<info.activeSel.length; cntSel++){
      cell = document.getElementById(info.activeSel[cntSel][0]);
      var fact = (content/100)*cell;
      var content1 = fact+cell;
      sapbi_rig_plan_setContent(cell, content1);
    }
  } else {
       alert('Please Enter the Valid Qty only');
  }
}
```

Please note : I am not a JavaScript developer, I am a SAP BW-IP developer.